# window function identifying the 1st, 2nd, etc. day of week of the month

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I have a utility calendar table which looks like this:

[image]

| DATE | DAY_OF_WEEK | DAY_OF_MONTH | MONTH | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | Sunday | 1 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-02 | Monday | 2 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-03 | Tuesday | 3 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-04 | Wednesday | 4 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-05 | Thursday | 5 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-06 | Friday | 6 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-07 | Saturday | 7 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-08 | Sunday | 8 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-09 | Monday | 9 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-10 | Tuesday | 10 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-11 | Wednesday | 11 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-12 | Thursday | 12 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-13 | Friday | 13 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-14 | Saturday | 14 | 1 | 2023 |
| 2023-01-15 | Sunday | 15 | 1 | 2023 |

I am trying to add a column which signifies the first weekday of its kind in a month. In this column, rows 1-7 should say 1, rows 8-14 should say 2, and so on until February 2023, and the pattern resets.

It seems to me that a window function is necessary here, however RANK() just counts the days of the month when partitioned by month, or just counts the days in the week when partitioned by an extracted field which is the week of the year. I don't see how [the other window functions could be used to generate the correct results, either](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic).

Comment: Please could you edit your question and add the simple data as text not image ?

Comment: Can you also explain what you mean by “the first weekday of its kind in a month”? You seem to be indicating that the first 7 days are week 1 etc but is that just because your data happens to start on a Sunday? If the first of the month was a Wednesday would days 1-4 be week 1, 5-11 week 2 etc? Assuming that the day of the week matters, does your week start on a Sunday, Monday or something else?

Comment: @NickW if the month starts on a Wednesday, then that is the first Wednesday of the month and should have the value 1, and so should the following 6 days until we reach the second Wednesday of the month.  I am expecting that there will be an uneven count of each weekday per month, since that's how the calendar works.

Comment: If your calculation is just 7 day increments then why not just divide the day of the month by 7 and add 1?

Comment: @NickW that doesn't work since the 7th row would go into the second week ((7/7) + 1 = 2) and we need seven values per week

Comment: Try divide the day of the month by 7 and CEIL the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `dense_rank` function as the following:

```
select *,
  dense_rank() over (partition by year, month, day_of_week order by date) as rnk
from table_name
order by date
```

Or use `((day_of_month-1) /7)+1`. (based on a comment from @NickW)

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TXNsDgTM)